# org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector - Leading to OOM

Tags: java, apache-kafka

So I have a Java service which uses the `kafka-clients` sdk in a while loop to fetch from Kafka Topics. I am getting OOM (out of memory) issues running a single consumer after about 3-5 minutes of execution.

I have captured a Heap Dump which points to `org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector` holding onto allocated memory. Eventually I get `GC overhead limit exceeded` error.

[image: Heap Dump Image]

I have followed the following two resources with no luck as my issue doesn't seem to be SSL related (I'm using PlainText).

[Kafka JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7304)

[Debugging a memory leak in Apache Kafka®](https://medium.com/@jnvrro/debugging-a-memory-leak-in-apache-kafka-64bfa7396371)

Here are some of my kafka properties:

```json
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
enable.auto.commit = true
exclude.internal.topics = true
fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
fetch.min.bytes = 1
max.partition.fetch.bytes = 20000000
max.poll.interval.ms = 30000
max.poll.records = 1000
```

Comment: What version of client are you using? Have you tried using another one?

Comment: I'm currently using 2.2.0, I did try 2.8.0 with no luck. Let me give that another try.

Comment: Alternatively, have you simply tried to increase your heap size for your app?

Comment: Yea that puts a bandage on it, works short term for sure. I actually have had some luck by lowering `fetch.max.bytes = 52428800` to 10MB. Still investigating.

Answer (score 1):

May have figured it out:

When my consumer was connecting to the broker the property `fetch.max.bytes` was defaulting to `52428800` which comes out to 52MB per batch.

My consumer was polling every 100ms. I'm assuming this frequency, combined with the size of each batch was overwhelming the Garbage Collector. I modified this parameters down to a more reasonable number and everything seems to be working fine now.